# how to configure camel rest dsl producer for HTTPS rest call

Tags: apache, apache-camel

It still connects on http, rather https and fails:

> org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://client.api.net/health with statusCode: 404

```
restConfiguration()
.component("restlet")
.host(Constant.CLIENT_URL)
.scheme("https").port(443)          
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
```

Comment: Not finding proper documentation to change from http to https scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I have used xml for defining Camel Rest DSL check it out if it helps you, I Have tested this function using Postman rest client, my POST URL is http://localhost:8080/orders/postOrder and the JSON body is sent to the direct:start route. You can define your own destination according to your own use case

```
 <bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />
        <bean id="RestletComponentService" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <ref bean="RestletComponent" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

<!--This is the post url -->
<!-- http://localhost:8080/orders/postOrder -->
        <restConfiguration bindingMode="json" component="servlet" />
        <rest path="/orders">
            <post uri="/postOrder" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
                <to uri="direct:start" />
            </post>
        </rest>
```

Remember to add camel-restlet and camel-http dependency if your using maven

Comment: Yes you need to setup TLS/SSL on the restlet component itself for have this enabled in Rest DSL